# Validate field with name stored in multidimensional array in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have array type field like

```
foreach ($row as $data) {
    {{ Form::text('fieldname['.$data.']',$value,['class'=>'form-control']) }}

    {{ Form::text('fieldname['.$data.']',$value,['class'=>'form-control']) }}
}
```

Now in my controller i want to validate these field (i.e. required or not) based on condition.

> Controller :

```
  foreach($req)...
     if(somevalue)
     {
         $rules[$fieldname['name']] = 'required';
     }
    }
```

Here the issue is i have common name for the field, so i will i specify the name that is to be validated in the rules array.

Comment: u can try this https://laravel.com/docs/master/validation#validating-arrays

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you get an **array** from a **Request**, where **product** is an **array**. For validate this **array**, you can use validate method like this.

```
$validatedData = $request->validate([
       "name" => "required", // non array
       "product"    => "required|array", // check product is an array
       "product.*"  => "required", // validate all field required in this array
       "product.image.*"  => "image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif|max:2048", // validate an array field
    ]
);
```